# geocode a marker in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I was roaming on this site for any info on geocoding a marker. However, I have tried some of the answers but I did not manage to make it work (I am an amateur when it comes to coding), so could someone please help me with the geocoding of my marker? Apparantly, the marker is missing when using this code. I need to geocode postcode in this case, which is the zip code 1058JA. Thanks in advance!

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var Postcode;

Postcode = '1058JA';

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.368465, 4.903921);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


function codeAddress() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode( {'address': document.getElementById("address").value },
          function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              Postcode = results[0].geometry.location;
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
              {
                center: Postcode,
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              });
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:results[0].geometry.location,
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
            } 
            else {
              document.getElementById("address").value = status;
            }
          }
        );

      }  
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Function `codeAddress()` is never called. And `map` would be created again inside it.

Comment: [Simple geocoder example](http://www.geocodezip.com/GMapsExampleV3b.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1) `codeAddress` is never called (as Anto Jurković notes).

2) A new instance of map is created within codeAddress if it were ever called which is redundant.

3) While you've specified Postcode as a string at the top of the code, the geocoder is looking for the value of a input element instead.

Your code should something like this:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var Postcode;

Postcode = '1058JA';

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.368465, 4.903921);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    codeAddress();
}

function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': Postcode }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("address").value = status;
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/n4b4d/31/)